# PDFView as Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, pdfview, composable

I think I'm almost there, but...

I have wrapped a `com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView` in a composable like so:

```
@Composable
fun PDFView(
    byteArray: ByteArray
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red),

        factory = { context ->
            PDFView(context, null)
        },
        update = { pdfView ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PDF view UPDATE called")
            pdfView.fromBytes(byteArray)
            Log.d(TAG, "Page Count: ${pdfView.pageCount}")
            Log.d(TAG, String(bytes = byteArray))
        }
    )
}
```

However, I'm just not seeing the PDF displayed when calling the view as follows:

```
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val filename = "example.pdf"
    val fileInputStream = context.assets.open(filename)
    val byteArray = fileInputStream.readBytes()
    
    PDFView(byteArray = byteArray)
```

Now, I know the PDF exist because the `Log.d` output from the `update` callback does produce the raw PDF content.
However, the `Page Count` log output indicates 0 pages.

What I'm I missing? Why is the PDF not displayed?

**UPDATE**:

Figured it out. You need to add a `.load()` like so:

```
    pdfView
        .fromBytes(byteArray)
        .load()
```

Comment: have you tried loading the same file in XML based app? Most probably this issue has nothing to do with Compose.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Philip. I figured it out. Turns out you need to call a `.load()` on pdfView for it actually display a pdf.